# Can't setup GDT on Multiboot (Triple fault?)

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, osdev, multiboot

i am trying to setup GDT from my simple kernel that uses multiboot and i don't know what's happening (i think it's triple fault). when using the qemu monitor trying to debug it but i didn't success addressing the issue so i came here.

here is the code:

```
// boot.S
#ifndef __BOOT_S
#define __BOOT_S

#define ASM_FILE                1
#include <multiboot.h>

#ifdef ASM_HAS_USCORE
#       define EXT(sym)                         _ ## sym        // EXT(main) = _main
#else
#       define EXT(sym)                         sym             // EXT(main) = main
#endif

#ifdef __ELF__
#       define AOUT_KLUDGE                      0
#else
#       define AOUT_KLUDGE                      MULTIBOOT_AOUT_KLUDGE
#endif

#define STACK_SIZE                              0x4000
#define MULTIBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS                  MULTIBOOT_PAGE_ALIGN | MULTIBOOT_MEMORY_INFO | AOUT_KLUDGE

.text
.globl start, _start
.globl __lgdt // , __sgdt
// .globl __lidt, __sidt

__lgdt:
        pushl %eax
        pushl %ebp
        mov %esp, %ebp
        cli
        pushl (%eax)
        lgdt (%esp)
        ljmp $0x08, $__flush_end

__flush_end:
        popl %eax
        popl %ebp
        movl %ebp, %esp

start:
_start:
        jmp     mb_entry
        .align  MULTIBOOT_INFO_ALIGN

mb_header:
        .long   MULTIBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC
        .long   MULTIBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS
        .long   -(MULTIBOOT_HEADER_MAGIC + MULTIBOOT_HEADER_FLAGS)
#ifndef __ELF__
        /* header_addr */
        .long   mb_header
        /* load_addr */
        .long   _start
        /* load_end_addr */
        .long   _edata
        /* bss_end_addr */
        .long   _end
        /* entry_addr */
        .long   mb_entry
#else /* ! __ELF__ */
        .long   0
        .long   0
        .long   0
        .long   0
        .long   0
#endif /* __ELF__ */

mb_entry:
        movl    $(stack + STACK_SIZE), %esp
        pushl   $0
        popfl

        pushl   %ebx
        pushl   %eax

        call    EXT(main)
        ret

loop:
        hlt
        jmp     loop

.comm   stack, STACK_SIZE

#endif
```

```
// gdt.h
#include <stdint.h>

#define SEG_DESCTYPE(x)  ((x) << 0x04) // Descriptor type (0 for system, 1 for code/data)
#define SEG_PRES(x)      ((x) << 0x07) // Present
#define SEG_SAVL(x)      ((x) << 0x0C) // Available for system use
#define SEG_LONG(x)      ((x) << 0x0D) // Long mode
#define SEG_SIZE(x)      ((x) << 0x0E) // Size (0 for 16-bit, 1 for 32)
#define SEG_GRAN(x)      ((x) << 0x0F) // Granularity (0 for 1B - 1MB, 1 for 4KB - 4GB)
#define SEG_PRIV(x)     (((x) &  0x03) << 0x05)   // Set privilege level (0 - 3)

#define SEG_DATA_RD        0x00 // Read-Only
#define SEG_DATA_RDA       0x01 // Read-Only, accessed
#define SEG_DATA_RDWR      0x02 // Read/Write
#define SEG_DATA_RDWRA     0x03 // Read/Write, accessed
#define SEG_DATA_RDEXPD    0x04 // Read-Only, expand-down
#define SEG_DATA_RDEXPDA   0x05 // Read-Only, expand-down, accessed
#define SEG_DATA_RDWREXPD  0x06 // Read/Write, expand-down
#define SEG_DATA_RDWREXPDA 0x07 // Read/Write, expand-down, accessed
#define SEG_CODE_EX        0x08 // Execute-Only
#define SEG_CODE_EXA       0x09 // Execute-Only, accessed
#define SEG_CODE_EXRD      0x0A // Execute/Read
#define SEG_CODE_EXRDA     0x0B // Execute/Read, accessed
#define SEG_CODE_EXC       0x0C // Execute-Only, conforming
#define SEG_CODE_EXCA      0x0D // Execute-Only, conforming, accessed
#define SEG_CODE_EXRDC     0x0E // Execute/Read, conforming
#define SEG_CODE_EXRDCA    0x0F // Execute/Read, conforming, accessed

#define GDT_CODE_PL0 SEG_DESCTYPE(1) | SEG_PRES(1) | SEG_SAVL(0) | \
                SEG_LONG(0)     | SEG_SIZE(1) | SEG_GRAN(1) | \
                SEG_PRIV(0)     | SEG_CODE_EXRD

#define GDT_DATA_PL0 SEG_DESCTYPE(1) | SEG_PRES(1) | SEG_SAVL(0) | \
                SEG_LONG(0)     | SEG_SIZE(1) | SEG_GRAN(1) | \
                SEG_PRIV(0)     | SEG_DATA_RDWR

#define GDT_CODE_PL3 SEG_DESCTYPE(1) | SEG_PRES(1) | SEG_SAVL(0) | \
                SEG_LONG(0)     | SEG_SIZE(1) | SEG_GRAN(1) | \
                SEG_PRIV(3)     | SEG_CODE_EXRD

#define GDT_DATA_PL3 SEG_DESCTYPE(1) | SEG_PRES(1) | SEG_SAVL(0) | \
                SEG_LONG(0)     | SEG_SIZE(1) | SEG_GRAN(1) | \
                SEG_PRIV(3)     | SEG_DATA_RDWR

int64_t create_descriptor(uint32_t base, uint32_t limit, uint16_t flag) {
        uint64_t descriptor;
        // Create the high 32 bit segment
        descriptor  =  limit       & 0x000F0000;         // set limit bits 19:16
        descriptor |= (flag <<  8) & 0x00F0FF00;         // set type, p, dpl, s, g, d/b, l and avl fields
        descriptor |= (base >> 16) & 0x000000FF;         // set base bits 23:16
        descriptor |=  base        & 0xFF000000;         // set base bits 31:24

        // Shift by 32 to allow for low part of segment
        descriptor <<= 32;

        // Create the low 32 bit segment
        descriptor |= base  << 16;                       // set base bits 15:0
        descriptor |= limit  & 0x0000FFFF;               // set limit bits 15:0

        return descriptor;
}

struct gdt_pointer_s {
        uint16_t size;
        uint32_t offset;
} __attribute__((packed));

#ifndef __DEBUG
extern void __lgdt(void* gdtp);
#endif

#ifdef __DEBUG
#       define printf           __builtin_printf
#endif

int setup_gdt(void) {
        uint64_t gdt[5];
        gdt[0] = create_descriptor(0, 0, 0);
        gdt[1] = create_descriptor(0, 0x000FFFFF, (GDT_CODE_PL0));
        gdt[2] = create_descriptor(0, 0x000FFFFF, (GDT_DATA_PL0));
        gdt[3] = create_descriptor(0, 0x000FFFFF, (GDT_CODE_PL3));
        gdt[4] = create_descriptor(0, 0x000FFFFF, (GDT_DATA_PL3));

        #ifdef __DEBUG
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i += 1) {
                printf("%lx\n", gdt[i]);
        }
        #endif

        struct gdt_pointer_s gdtp;
        gdtp.size = sizeof(gdt) - 1;
        gdtp.offset = (uint32_t)&gdt[0];
        #ifndef __DEBUG
        __lgdt(&gdtp);
        #endif
        return 0;
}
```

i did some modifications to the `setup_gdt` function where it's know setting the gdt entries to `0xfafafafa`

```
x/64x $esp
00007f9c: 0x0000185b 0x00007fc2 0x00000000 0x00001846
00007fac: 0x00007fc8 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
00007fbc: 0x2badb002 0x00020000 0x00007fc8 0xfafafafa
00007fcc: 0x00000000 0xfafafafa 0x00000000 0xfafafafa
00007fdc: 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00008008
00007fec: 0x00010000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000
....
```

i was playing around from last night until now also i've searched about it. i searched for it across the internet and found this [post](https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=32781) on osdev forums but it didn't help.

Comment: Your `__lgdt` function has a number of problems. It should probably be something more like `__llgdt:`
        `mov 4(%esp), %eax`
        `lgdt (%eax)`

        `mov $0x10, %eax`
        `mov %eax, %ds`
        `mov %eax, %es`
        `mov %eax, %fs`
        `mov %eax, %gs`
        `mov %eax, %ss`
        `jmp $0x08, $1f` `1: ret`

Comment: You also have `uint64_t gdt[5];` inside `setup_gdt`. Once your function goes out of scope that array that will be on the stack will be invalid and in the future the CPU accessing that data (the GDT) will likely fail as the stack gets clobbered. You should move `uint64_t gdt[5];` outside of `setup_gdt` at global scope.

Comment: If your debugger doesn't tell you which faults let to a triple-fault, get a better debugger.  I think QEMU has some logging options. Or there's Bochs which has a built-in debugger which can pretty-print page tables and GDT entries so you can verify that they mean what you intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank God Solved.

boot.S:

```
__lgdt:
        mov 4(%esp), %eax
        lgdt (%eax)
        mov $0x10, %eax
        mov %eax, %ds
        mov %eax, %es
        mov %eax, %fs
        mov %eax, %gs
        mov %eax, %ss
        jmp $0x08, $1f
1:
        ret
```

gdt.h: **NOTE:** the __lgdt accepts a value not referance and this value must be the gdt decriptor pointer. Thanks to Michael Petch.

```
extern void __lgdt(u32);
...
u64_t gdt[5];               // declared globaly
struct gdt_pointer_s gdtp;  // same

int setup_gdt(void) {
        gdt[0] = create_descriptor(0, 0, 0);
        gdt[1] = create_descriptor(0, 0x000FFFFF, (GDT_CODE_PL0));
        gdt[2] = create_descriptor(0, 0x000FFFFF, (GDT_DATA_PL0));
        gdt[3] = create_descriptor(0, 0x000FFFFF, (GDT_CODE_PL3));
        gdt[4] = create_descriptor(0, 0x000FFFFF, (GDT_DATA_PL3));

        #ifdef __DEBUG
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i += 1) {
                printf("%lx\n", gdt[i]);
        }
        #endif
        gdtp.size = sizeof(gdt) - 1;
        gdtp.offset = (uint32_t)&gdt[0];
        #ifndef __DEBUG
        __lgdt(&gdtp);
        #endif
        return 0;
}
```